# Three.JS OBJ Model not showing

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have .obj model, than i made (found) in c4d and exported it with scale 1 in meters. Than i try to load it in Three.js with OBJLoader, no errors, but model not showing. What's the problem with this

```
<script src="http://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
<script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader.js"></script>
<body style="margin:0;padding:0;">
</body>
<script>
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 2000);
    var render = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    camera.position.set(0, 0, 53);

    render.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(canvas = render.domElement);

    render.setClearColor(0x111111, 1);

    function loadScene() {
        var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
        loader.load("./fox.obj", function(model) {
            model.traverse(function(child) {
                if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                    child.material.color = 0xffb830;
                }
            });
            model.position.set(0, 0, -53);
            scene.add(model);
            window.model = model;
        });
        render.render(scene, camera);
    }

    window.onload = loadScene;
</script>
```

Comment: not the answer : put javascript inside head or body.

Comment: than doesn't make any matter, at all

Comment: You can try to use the boundingbox helper http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras.Helpers/BoundingBoxHelper to check if the position and size of loaded model are correct.

Comment: this code doesn't have a render loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made it work by: **(simpler correction below, in UPDATE)**

1 - Removing this line:

```
render.render(scene, camera);
```

2 - Adding this piece of code after the initializations:

```
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    render.render( scene, camera );
}
animate();
```

3 - Also by using a different source for the three.js library. I included the local copy I'm currently using in another project, and it worked. Probably you're fetching it from an out-of-date source... Try to download the file directly from the download link: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/archive/master.zip

You should also try to add OrbitControls to the scene so that you can orbit/navigate by the scene, because the object could be bigger than you expect and not showing (apparently) because of that.
You can add orbit controls by including the OrbitControls.js available in the three.js source, and adding the following line to your code:

```
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, render.domElement );
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Just call the render inside the function of the load method, like ManoDestra suggested:

```
loader.load("./fox.obj", function(model) {
    model.traverse(function(child) {
        if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
            child.material.color = 0xffb830;
        }
    });
    model.position.set(0, 0, -53);
    scene.add(model);
    window.model = model;
    render.render(scene, camera);
});
```

Comment: Funny, i completely missed the fact that there is no render loop setup. I stopped reading after the line that positions the loaded model.

Comment: I think mano destra's answer is more correct. You are extending the original code by adding interactivity through the orbit controller and a render loop. If the requirement is for this to only be rendered once, it should be done after loading the object.

Comment: The orbit controller was just a suggestion to the user for debugging only (trying to find the object that could be larger than expected, or in a different position). About the need of a render loop, I also thought that calling the renderer function only once after loading the object would be enough, but I tested the code, and it didn't work. By adding the render loop, it worked perfectly.

Comment: Nevermind. I didn't test it right. I'll edit with a simpler correction.

Comment: It might be actually how three does things, if there were two webglrenderer.render() calls right after one another it would probably work without the loop.

Comment: Brilliant! Spent almost 2 days to replace 1 line!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're rendering your scene before the object has loaded.

Place your render.render(scene, camera) call in such a way that it gets called only after your model has loaded. E.g.

```
function loadScene() {
    var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    loader.load("./fox.obj", function(model) {
        model.traverse(function(child) {
            if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                child.material.color = 0xffb830;
            }
        });
        model.position.set(0, 0, -53);
        scene.add(model);
        window.model = model;
        render.render(scene, camera);
    });
}
```

I would also ensure that all of your source exists in the head section (or the tail of your HTML, if that's your preference). Then, simply call your initialization code on the load event of the window. And, as stated above, only render the scene for the first time, after all of your assets have been loaded.

You may also require a call to look at your scene, for example...

```
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
```

Oh, also, child.material.color is an object e.g. `child.material.color = { r:1, g:1, b:1 }`.

Comment: Why is this an issue? Three.js supports adding and removing nodes from a scene graph ie. you can start rendering, then load something, then add it to the scene, all the while running some kind of rendering logic (either constant updates, or something more complicated). This has zero (0) impact on whether this thing will be drawn or not. Sure, the camera may not be looking at the object, but some assumptions can be made. THREE is right handed, so these numbers do make sense. A default camera looks down -z, it's moved to z==53, object to z==-53, there is 106 units between the camera and object.

Comment: I apologize for the comment, your answer is actually completely correct. He is rendering the scene only once before having anything loaded. I'd only argue maybe with the wording, this in itself is still not the issue, the issue is that he is not rendering anything afterwards. This code is most likely missing the render loop. I simply stopped reading after the line that positions the object.

Comment: Given the code, and the requirement to render the scene only once (no render loop) your answer is the only valid one here.

Comment: Thanks for the qualification. Yeah, there is no loop here to continually render the scene. And given the single render, it has to occur after the model has loaded. There's still some more to be done here to make it airtight and robust, but at least it paves the way for seeing his model rendered so he can move on :) The units is a fair comment, but I don't know what his model is like. I had to use one of my own and change the figures a bit.

Answer (score 1):

1. Apply `THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:'red'})` to all your loaded meshes, to eliminate things like missing normals, missing lights, missing textures etc *(This material should require none of this in order to work)*.
2. Look at `model.children[N].geometry.vertices` to see if you have valid values there